# how to get item from rac_sequence, reactive cocoa, ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa, racsignal, racsequence

I am parsing the needed links which is in the header of the response from the server. My header looks like

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *  Age → 0 Cache-Control →
>   private,must-revalidate
>
> Connection → keep-alive
>
> Content-Encoding → gzip  Content-Type → application/json
>
> Date → Sat, 13 Jun 2015 15:58:56 GMT  ETag →
>   W/"cb38bb07f1635fd6aba5969985bf0607"
>
> Link →  http://thisIsCurrentlink&limit=24; 
>   rel="next",http://thisIsLastlink&limit=24; 
>   rel="last",http://thisIsFirstlink&limit=24; rel="first",<>; 
>   rel="prev"
>
> Server → nginx
>
> Vary → Accept-Encoding
>
> X-Total-Count → 131
>
> transfer-encoding → chunked

By doing this, I can get the `links` array which contains all links

```
NSString *linkHeader = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)operation.response  allHeaderFields][@"Link"];
NSArray *links = [linkHeader componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Then I am doing the following to get all links I needed

```
RACSequence *sequence = [links.rac_sequence map:^id(NSString* item) {
                NSError *error;
                NSLog(@"item is %@",item);

                NSRegularExpression *regex  =   [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<(.*)>" options:0 error:&error];
                NSString *actualLink;

                if (regex != nil) {
                    NSTextCheckingResult *result    =   [regex firstMatchInString:item
                                                                          options:0
                                                                            range:NSMakeRange(0, item.length)
                                                         ];
                    if (result) {
                        NSRange range    =   [result rangeAtIndex:1];
                        actualLink       =   [item substringWithRange:range];
                        NSLog(@"actualLink is %@",actualLink);

                        return [RACSequence return:actualLink];

                    }
                }
                return [RACSequence empty];

            }];
```

Right now `sequence` is containing all links which are

```
http://thisIsCurrentlink&limit=24
http://thisIsLastlink&limit=24
http://thisIsFirsttlink&limit=24
```

My question is how can I access each item from above `sequence`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `array` method, which converts RACSequence into an array.

Also, you don't need to use `RACSequence return:`, that's creating sequences within your sequence, just return the usual string and nil, then use a `filter` after the `map` to remove all nil values before trying to extract it as an array.

Example:

```
NSArray *actualLinks = [[links.rac_sequence map:^id(NSString* item) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSLog(@"item is %@",item);

            NSRegularExpression *regex  =
            [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<(.*)>" options:0 error:&error];
            NSString *actualLink = nil;

            if (regex != nil) {
                NSTextCheckingResult *result = [regex firstMatchInString:item
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        range:NSMakeRange(0, item.length)];
                if (result) {
                    NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
                    actualLink = [item substringWithRange:range];
                    NSLog(@"actualLink is %@",actualLink);
                }
            }
            return actualLink;
        }] ignore:nil].array;
```

Comment: you can use `-ignore` method with `nil`: parameter instead of the `filter`

Comment: @MichałCiuba That's a super cool method, I'll try and remember that.